# How to implement stripe 3d secure that will work for both 3dsecure supported and unsupported cards?

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I have implemented 3D secure stripe which is working correctly,but i want to make it working for other unsupported cards also.

3D secure document says - The behavior of, and support for, 3D Secure can vary across card networks and types. For cards that are not supported, perform a regular card payment instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PaymentIntents support non-3DS cards as well, it just skips the authentication step if the card provided isn't enrolled in 3DS.

So if you implemented PaymentIntents then you already support both 3DS and non-3DS cards.